# How to store and retrieve a custom class

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

NSUserDefaults won't accept custom classes. So how can these objects be stored and retrieved?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make your class implement the NSCoding protocol before it can be serialized in the user defaults.

See: [Archives and Serializations Programing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1)